# What is the best way to develop an Elastic Beanstalk Django application locally?

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, local

I have recently deployed my Django application on Elastic Beanstalk.

I have everything working now, but I'm curious what the best way to develop locally is.

Currently, after I make a change locally, I have to `commit the changes via git` and then run `eb deploy`. This process takes 1-3 minutes which is not ideal for making changes.

The Django application will not run on my local machine, as it is configured for EB.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, having to deploy remotely during development isn't best practice.

Have you considered Docker?

To run a typical Django app locally using Docker, you'll need to dockerize:

- The Django app
- Database eg Postgres
- Worker eg Celery
- Local mailer eg Mailhog

Not a very long list.

Obviously you'll add or remove from that list depending on how complex or simple your app is.